# How to make the markers get bigger on zoom/getting current zoom value JVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jvectormap

So I want the markers to get bigger after how much it is zoomed in. I guess I could figure out how to make the marker size depend on the zoom value, but I dont know how to obtain zoom value.

I have tried to find some documentation on this but it seems like there is none.

So i hope one of you intelligent people know :)

All help appreciated

***edit:***

So i make the map div:

```
<div id="world-map" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; height: 460px;"></div>
```

To make the map script i have a php file that goes trough a folder finding other folders with corresponding place names and coordinate files inside(reason for this system is so i can print the pictures inside the folders when you press the marker you can see the pictures from the place)

The php script echoes this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#world-map").vectorMap({
  map: "world_mill",
   scaleColors: ["#C8EEFF", "#0071A4"],
normalizeFunction: "polynomial",
zoomMax: 1000,

hoverOpacity: 0.7,
onMarkerClick: function(e, code){
  var mapObj = $("#world-map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
var idx = code; // optional
var name = mapObj.markers[idx].config.name;
var latitude = mapObj.markers[idx].config.latLng[0];
var longitude = mapObj.markers[idx].config.latLng[1];
namePlace = name;
$.ajax({                    
url: "updatePlace.php",     
type: "GET", // performing a POST request
data : {
  data1 : name // will be accessible in $_POST["data1"]
},
dataType: "json",                   
success: function(data)         
{

placesArray = data;  
newPlace();
} 
});
},
hoverColor: false,
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    r: 2,
    fill: "#188a9a",
    stroke: "#383f47"
  }
},
backgroundColor: "#383f47",
//this will be done for each folder
markers: [{latLng: [" . $long . ", " . $lati ."], name: '" . $placeFolder[$i] ."'}]; 
] });
});
```

The php echo is printed inside the html code by using cookies. Whatever i echo in the php will be the same as writing it in script inside the html file.

Comment: use `onViewportChange`, the second parameter is the `scaleFactor,` this means, if your initial scale is equal 1, the scaleFactor will be your zoom. But... i believe is usual in all maps the markers are always keeping the same size (nasty, huh?) Maybe think about to set a minimum size, or they will disappear or be un-clickable.

Comment: Ohhh, seems difficult. The reason i want to do this is because it is difficult to click on the markers since you have to press twice and the markers are small @deblocker

Comment: if you just only need a human-finger-size, setting the initial size of the markers is very easy... just look in the docs. If you will try to code the markers resize based on the `scaleFactor`, please create a Plunker with a simple stub, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I know i can easily change the r of the markers, But the problem is that i am going to have so mang markers that it would be hard to see Where the marker belongs to When it is as big as What would be easy to use with a touchscreen. Going to Try and see How hard it is to do the resize after.

Comment: Added the code now @deblocker

Comment: Do you know how i can update the marker size when Viewport is changed? i guess i cant call the marker style inside the onViewportChange function? @deblocker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the standard built-in markers of jVectorMap, you can't use CSS to increase the width of the markers, because the `radius` is a SVG attribute.

Here is an example of how to increase the size of the standard round SVG markers of jVectorMap by setting directly the `radius` attribute. Zoom in and you will see the markers expanding.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#map").vectorMap({
    map: "world_mill",
    backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
    zoomOnScroll: true,
    regionStyle: {
      initial: { fill: "lightgrey" }
    },
    markerStyle: {
      initial: { fill: '#F8E23B', stroke: '#383f47' }
    },
    markers: [
      {latLng: [40.372338, 49.85211], name: 'BAKU'},
      {latLng: [1.291432, 103.86391], name: 'MARINA BAY'},
      {latLng: [47.581711, 19.250611], name: 'HUNGARORING'} 
    ],
    onViewportChange: function(event, scaleFactor){
      var map = $("#map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
      if(map) {
        var markers = map.markers,
            min = 5, 
            max = 18,
            r = ~~Math.min(Math.max(min * scaleFactor, min), max);
        for(var m in markers) {
          var el = markers[m].element,
              style = el.config.style;
          el.shape.node.setAttribute('r', r);
          style.initial.r = r;
          style.hover.r = r;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jvectormap.com/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you haven't specified in your question how you are defining the markers, and which size you need, You may play with this example to adapt it (but, i believe is is a good starting point).

Comment: Thanks that really worked. Going to tweak it so it goes a little slower on adding size to the marker but really thanks!