# Set marker image width/height in jVectorMap

Tags: jquery, svg, jvectormap

Unfortunately setting the markerStyle when creating a new jVectorMap doesn't affect the SVG image attributes.

```
window.mapMarkers = [];
window.mapMarkers.push({
    name: 'Test',
    coords: [12.345, 12.345]
});

new jvm.Map({
    container: $('#map'),
    map: 'en',
    series: {
        markers: [{
            attribute: 'image',
            scale: { 'marker': 'marker.png' },
            values: window.mapMarkers.reduce(function(p, c, i) { p[i] = 'marker'; return p; }, {})
        }]
    },
    markerStyle: {
        initial: {
            width: 42, height: 58
        }
    }
});
```

How can I overwrite the SVG width/height image attributes in the map without changing the [jvectormap library](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/) source code? Setting the dimensions via CSS only works in WebKit but not Firefox and Co.

Comment: here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45654430/4845566

Answer (score 1):

Look for 'svg-image-element.js'.
By default the size of the svg-image is the size of the used image.

```
that.width = img[0].width;
that.height = img[0].height;
```

To change it, simply change img[0].width / height to whatever you need.